# php mysql nested query "where not in"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables test_category and results:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_category` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sub_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  KEY `sub_code` (`sub_code`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `results` (
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_taken` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`res_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `score_type` (`score_type`)
)
```

i want to select some columns that exist on test_category but doesn't exist in results.

here is the sql i've tried but it does not work:

```
select _id, score_type from test_category where _id in ('13') and not in(select score_type from results where user_id=349);
```

Comment: I guess it should looks like : `and score_type not in`

Comment: @valex but datatype is differ in both tables.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ You're right. The same name but different types ...

Comment: @valex that's why I have not mapped these columns for NOT IN.

Answer (score 2):

You missed to mention the column name after AND

Try this,

```
SELECT _id, score_type FROM test_category WHERE _id IN
('13') AND _id NOT IN(SELECT score_type FROM results WHERE user_id=349);
```

Comment: i see, so that's where i was wrong. your sql command works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You query should be this:

```
select _id, score_type 
    FROM test_category 
      WHERE _id in ('13') 
       AND _id NOT IN (select score_type 
                         FROM results 
                           WHERE user_id=349);
```